# How to quit QEMU monitor?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, telnet, qemu

I launched KVM VM with this command:

```
kvm /kvm/hdd/v1/v1-1.raw -m 512 -daemonize -smp 2 -nographic -net nic,model=virtio,macaddr=aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:01 -net tap,ifname=tap0 -monitor telnet:localhost:7001,server,nowait,nodelay
```

Then I connect to the monitor via telnet. But when I'm quitting the monitor with 'quit' or 'q', the VM stops. Why and how to quit without stopping the VM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try to 'telnet' way? I.e.:

```
Ctrl+]
telnet> quit
```

Answer (score 10):

When connected to the monitor via telnet, anything that you type will be interpreted as a command by the monitor itself. You can view the full list of commands in the [QEMU Emulator User Documentation](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#pcsys_005fmonitor), one of which is `quit` (or `q` for short).

To disconnect the telnet session you need to first use the telnet escape key which is Ctrl-] and then you can type `quit` when you see the `telnet>` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment using `Ctrl`+`[` and then `quit` worked